# How do I find an appropriate tag to use?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Sometimes I have no idea what tag to use on my questions. I look at the "popular tags" list but none of them are appropriate. I type a few characters of some words that describe what my question is about but none of the suggestions are right either. Sometimes I'm lucky and a good tag will pop up because the three or four letters I typed in are in the middle of that tag, but this happens rarely.

Most of the time I will find a tag that sort-of fits and post my question. A lot of the time someone more knowledgeable than me will edit my question by adding the correct tags (and possibly removing the original tag). Should I keep doing this or is there some other way of finding appropriate tags that I'm not yet aware of?

Comment: There is no magic formula. This is very specific to each question.

Comment: It's also specific to each site.  For example, on Arqade, you'd tag with the name of the game about which you're asking.  On Code Review, you'd tag with the programming language.

Answer (score 2):

If you have found yourself in a situation where you need to ask a question on the site, then you would have searched the site before asking it to see if it's been asked before. Therefore, what criteria did you use to do that search?

That search should've brought up some posts, and those posts will be tagged with something. If your question hasn't already been asked, or at least you can't find it using the search criteria you instinctively used, then it's a good bet that you should use that search criteria - and any tags it brings up - as the tags for your own post. That means whenever someone carries out the same, or similar search in future, they'll find your question.

Comment: Great suggestion to check the tags on similar posts! I'll try that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is the tags tab to see the tags that you can use. It is OK to use a tag that half-fits your question IMO, as tags are intended for your question to be filtered appropriately.

There were discussions earlier on if there should be a "universal" tag for new-users, that tell the more experienced users to edit and add some tags. But I cannot seem to find the post, and I am not sure if it got approved by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of the tags tab. Most sites seem to have between 1000 and 2000 tags. SO has over 55000. The words "haystack" and "needle" come to mind.